# Long yticklabels increase height of bar plot too much

Tags: pgfplots

With the help of Jake I'm able to create bar plots with variable heights ( [Space between bars, height and width of the plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84073/space-between-bars-height-and-width-of-the-plot) ). Some bar plots have single very long `yticklabel`s that need line breaks. To prevent printing `yticklabel`s into one another I have to increase “y” (see MWE). But “y” applies to every `yticklabel` even if it's not needed. The MWE shows a bar plot that grows more than necessary, not fitting on the page any more. Can “y” be increased only for bars with long yticklabels?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xbar, %
    y=-1.5cm,%
    bar width=0.5cm,%
    enlarge y limits={abs=0.45cm},
    xlabel={Häufigkeit},%
    symbolic y coords={
      Einhaltung der Hygienestandards,%
      Zeitintensität des Programms,%
      Zubereitung des O+G,%
      Lagerung des O+G,%
      Müllentsorgung und Reinigung,%
      Sonstige,%
      Keine Probleme,%
      Abstimmung mit dem Lieferanten/Warennahme/Lieferzeitpunkt,%
      Verteilung des O+G auf die Klassen,%
      Qualität der Lieferung/Lieferung an zwei aufeinanderfolgenden Tagen ist schlecht/bessere Verteilung,%
      Keine Lieferung an allen Schultagen/nach Ferien öfters holpriger Beginn,%
      Auswahl des Obstes,%
      Ausstattung mit Materialien (Schneidebrett),%
      Anmeldung zum SOP
    },%
    ytick=data,%
    yticklabel style={text width=5cm,align=right},%
    nodes near coords,%
    nodes near coords align={horizontal},%
    ]%
    \addplot table[col sep=comma,header=false] {%
      23, Einhaltung der Hygienestandards
      20, Zeitintensität des Programms
      18, Zubereitung des O+G
      16, Lagerung des O+G
      7, Müllentsorgung und Reinigung
      6, Sonstige
      4, Keine Probleme
      4, Abstimmung mit dem Lieferanten/Warennahme/Lieferzeitpunkt
      1, Verteilung des O+G auf die Klassen
      1, Qualität der Lieferung/Lieferung an zwei aufeinanderfolgenden Tagen ist schlecht/bessere Verteilung
      1, Keine Lieferung an allen Schultagen/nach Ferien öfters holpriger Beginn
      1, Auswahl des Obstes
      1, Ausstattung mit Materialien (Schneidebrett)
      1, Anmeldung zum SOP
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Corresponding plot (see page number in the lower left corner of the plot):
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `symbolic y coords` style places the bars at y=0,1,2,3,... . It is possible to change the placement options, i.e. to choose a different coordinate for "huge" labels manually.

This could be done by using `yticklabels` instead of `symbolic y coords` and by providing the y positions explicitly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xbar, %
    y=-1.5cm,%
    bar width=0.5cm,%
    enlarge y limits={abs=0.45cm},
    xlabel={Häufigkeit},%
    yticklabels={
      Einhaltung der Hygienestandards,%
      Zeitintensität des Programms,%
      Zubereitung des O+G,%
      Lagerung des O+G,%
      Müllentsorgung und Reinigung,%
      Sonstige,%
      Keine Probleme,%
      Abstimmung mit dem Lieferanten/Warennahme/Lieferzeitpunkt,%
      Verteilung des O+G auf die Klassen,%
      Qualität der Lieferung/Lieferung an zwei aufeinanderfolgenden Tagen ist schlecht/bessere Verteilung,%
      Keine Lieferung an allen Schultagen/nach Ferien öfters holpriger Beginn,%
      Auswahl des Obstes,%
      Ausstattung mit Materialien (Schneidebrett),%
      Anmeldung zum SOP
    },%
    ytick=data,%
    yticklabel style={text width=5cm,align=right},%
    nodes near coords,%
    nodes near coords align={horizontal},%
    ]%
    \addplot table[col sep=comma,header=false] {%
      23,0
      20,1
      18,2
      16,3
      7, 4
      6, 5
      4, 6
      4, 7
      1, 8
      1, 9
      1, 10.5
      1, 11.5
      1, 12.5
      1, 13.5
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here, I chose a different position for the last four entries.

You could also place the tick labels into the very same table and use `yticklabels from table` to load the labels; that would simplify the lookup for you.

**EDIT** Since the information of my last paragraph is of use to you, I added that one here:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma, header=false]{
      23,0,    Einhaltung der Hygienestandards
      20,1,    Zeitintensitaet des Programms
      18,2,    Zubereitung des O+G
      16,3,    Lagerung des O+G
      7, 4,    Muellentsorgung und Reinigung
      6, 5,    Sonstige
      4, 6,    Keine Probleme
      4, 7.2,  Abstimmung mit dem Lieferanten/Warennahme/Lieferzeitpunkt
      1, 8.5,  Verteilung des O+G auf die Klassen
      1, 10.5, Qualitaet der Lieferung/Lieferung an zwei aufeinanderfolgenden Tagen ist schlecht/bessere Verteilung
      1, 12.7, Keine Lieferung an allen Schultagen/nach Ferien oefters holpriger Beginn
      1, 14,   Auswahl des Obstes
      1, 15,   Ausstattung mit Materialien (Schneidebrett)
      1, 16,   Anmeldung zum SOP
}\datatable

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xbar, 
    y=-.8cm,
    bar width=0.5cm,
    enlarge y limits={abs=0.45cm},
    xlabel={Haeufigkeit},
    yticklabels from table={\datatable}{2},
    ytick=data,
    yticklabel style={text width=5cm,align=right},
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={horizontal},
    ]
    \addplot table [y=1, x=0] {\datatable};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you see, the code mentioned in your comment was *almost* right: except for a small misunderstanding. You said `\addplot table [y expr=\coordindex, x=0]`; probably a relic of some older prototype. Of course, `\coordindex` will ignore your carefully chosen positions. Writing `y=1` repairs it.

Note that `y=1, x=0` is *the same* as `y index=1, x index=0` in your case because you do not have column names (and pgfplots assigns column names = column indices). In general, it would be a good practice to use `y index=1, x index=0` in such a case.

Note furthermore that you do not need trailing `%` between adjacent keys in key-value-lists (although they do not hurt).

Comment: Thank you!! Though I don't know how to implement your last tip (https://dl.dropbox.com/u/18529526/pgfplots-beschriftung-platzieren.tex does not work) I can now make the first version up.

Comment: you almost got it - see my edit.

Comment: Thanks again! I even tried “y=1”. But I did not delete “y expr=\coordindex”; just because I'm not in the know. pgfplots is quite a cool package---but in some ways much too powerful for me … Thanks for pgfplots!