# pgfplots: Adjust gap between xbars

Tags: pgfplots

How am I able to set the distance between the bars and the distance between the bars and the axis?

If you only have a few bars, the gaps are way too big. By shrinking the total height, the gap between xbars and axis becomes too small.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{filecontents*}{datatable.txt}
one two
 A   1
 B   2
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    height=4cm,
    xbar,
    yticklabels from table={datatable.txt}{one},
    ytick=data
    ]
\addplot table [x=two,y expr=\coordindex] {datatable.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

Comment: I provided a different approach, see my answer. Nice MWE btw!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I use `width` and `height` to define the dimension of the whole plot.
- Then I use `enlarge y limits` to control the spacing between the bottom/top bar and the border of the plot.
- The `bar width` controls the width of the bars.
- In addition, as shown in [Space between bars, height and width of the plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84073), you can set the `y` key to define the physical `y` unit of one logical `y` unit (not shown in my code).

---

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{filecontents*}{datatable.txt}
one two
 A   1
 B   2
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    width = 50mm,
    height = 30mm,
    enlarge y limits  = 0.5,
    bar width = 5mm,
    yticklabels from table={datatable.txt}{one},
    ytick=data
    ]
\addplot table [x=two,y expr=\coordindex] {datatable.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

---

### Questions to the experts here

> How is the `xbar` plot organized? Is the y axis like a normal axis
>   with position 1, 2, 3, and so on and every entry increments is by 1?